# How can I get logs of the corresponding correlation id in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

There is a way to get logs of the corresponding **correlation id** in SharePoint Online without passing by Microsoft support?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get those logs yourself. Previously, some  [powershell/csom commandlets](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/03/view-tenant-uls-logs-in-sharepoint.html) used to work, but looks like MS has disabled them now.

The only way is to contact MS support.

There is user voice link I have mentioned below, you can upvote on it and hope that probably MS adds access some day in the future.

Uservoice link - [Access SPO ULS entries for correlation id](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/11485845-get-in-sharepoint-online-the-uls-entries-for-your)

Answer (score 3):

> Microsoft uses the Unified Logging System (ULS) in the SharePoint
>   Online environment. Sometimes we receive requests to share these ULS
>   logs with customers for troubleshooting and debugging scenarios.
>   Microsoft does not provide copies of ULS logs or any access to ULS
>   logs from SharePoint Online.
>   [Information about ULS log access for SharePoint Online](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3179146/information-about-uls-log-access-for-sharepoint-online)

I would try [Get-SPOTenantLogEntry](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161369.aspx), if that works for you.

```
$endTimeinUTC = Get-SPOTenantLogLastAvailableTimeInUtc
$startTimeinUTC = $endTimeinUTC.AddDays (-14)
$tenantlogs = Get-SPOTenantLogEntry -StartTimeinUtc $startTimeinUTC -EndTimeinUTC $endTimeinUTC -CorrelationId yourCorrelationId
```

If not, then you should contact support.

Comment: I have already used it but it returns nothing.

Comment: That method is hit and miss thing not 100% suces...i would try within 1 day of days range if get anything otherwise contact to MSFT for issue

Comment: This is what it says in Get-SPOTenantLogEntry page "For Beta 2, the only company logs available are for Business Connectivity Services (BCS)"