# Sharepoint Online - Upload Web Part Site AppCatalog - Deploy Error

Tags: spfx-webparts

I have a simple web-part Hello Word from the tutorial of "Build your first web part" from Microsoft. However, every time I upload web part, the column "Deployed" is checked to "No", but column "Tenant Deployed" is checked "Yes".

This is the error I'm having

```
Deployment failed.  
Correlation ID: 8f42129f-b0c5-a000-40fb-3b7377e8541d
```

This is my *package-Solution.json*

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
  "solution": {
    "name": "test-1-client-side-solution",
    "id": "00d7fc42-2ae8-451c-a23f-42142d53cae4",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "includeClientSideAssets": true,
    "skipFeatureDeployment": true
  },
  "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "solution/test-1.sppkg"
  }
}
```

I also tried the following commands.

```
gulp clean
gulp bundle
gulp bundle--ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: @harshalgite here:
` 
vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl
vti_extenderversion:SR|16.0.0.19423
`

Comment: SharePoint 2016?

Comment: yes, it's Sharepoint online 2016

Answer (score 0):

No need to run "gulp bundle" command.
Execute below commands:

```
gulp clean
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

---

*If the answer is helpful, please upvote and mark as accepted.*

Comment: After doing the commands above. My App package error message

"Deployment failed.  Correlation ID: 4145129f-a0b2-a000-d85a-d016b768719d"

Comment: Did you check the webpart in your local workbench?

Comment: Yes, it works like the Microsoft example and the terminal doesn't show any errors.

Comment: I always execute commands which I provided and it works perfectly. Do you have the "Contribute" permission for the "AppCatalog" site?

Comment: I'm a catalog Owner with full control permission. Is there any other solution to get the logs of the errors?

Comment: Please check this link: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224985/how-can-i-get-logs-of-the-corresponding-correlation-id-in-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app from app catalogue and wait for 20-30minutes and then try again.